# How to wide-space words in a given range in Python?

Tags: python, string, whitespace

Given a Python string, I want to wide-space occurrences of a given `word` substring inside the string `sentence` of a given range. I couldn't find an efficient and neat way to perform this algorithm.

I want to wide-space only words with indices within a given range of the `sentence` string, and the word must be exact (not surrounded by other word characters such as letters and digits). Punctuation and other symbols are ignored when counting word exactness.

So far, my function `widespace(sentence, word, start = None, end = None):` should wide-space a given `word` within a given range from `start` to `end`, but currently it looks quite inefficient and verbose. It also cannot detect exact word matches and ignore punctuation.

**Expected results**

1. All occurrences of the word will be affected if it is within `range(start, end)`, that means, index greater or equal than `start`, *strictly* less than `end`.
2. The exact match ignores punctuation, but is case sensitive. For example, if you want to match `"omg"`, it accepts `"omg!"`, and `"omg,"`, but it does not accept `"omg"` surrounded by other word characters, such as `"zomg"` or `"omgf"`

   - Word characters can include numbers, letters, hyphens, it is your preference.
3. `widespace("Foo, Bar, Baz!", "Baz")` becomes `Foo, Bar, B a z!`

   - The index is 10.
4. `widespace("Foo, Foo, Foo!", "Foo")` becomes `F o o, F o o, F o o!`

   - The indices are 0, 5, 10.
5. `widespace("Foo, Foo, Foo!", "Foo", start = 0, end = 2)` becomes
   `F o o, Foo, Foo!`

   - The indices are 0, 5, 10. Only the first one (index 0) gets affected.
6. `widespace("Foo, Foo, Foo!", "Foo", start = 0, end = 5)` becomes
   `F o o, Foo, Foo!` like the previous example

   - the indices are 0, 5, 10. Only the first one (index 0) gets affected since the second one exactly matches 5, which is out of range.
7. `widespace("Foo, Foo, Foo!", "Foo", start = 0, end = 6)` becomes
   `F o o, F o o, Foo!`

   - the indices are 0, 5, 10. Only the first two gets matched.
8. `widespace("Mulliganaceous Mulligan, OMG", "Mulligan")` should become
   `Mulliganaceous M u l l i g a n, OMG"`

   - `"Mulliganaceous"` is not an exact match. But `"Mulligan,"` counts as one because it is not surrounded by other word characters.
   - I currently have `M u l l i g a naceous M u l l i g a n`

**Current code**

As of now, I got it working, but the code is quite long, possibly inefficient, and cannot deal with exact matches and punctuation marks.

```
def widespace(sentence: str, word: str, start: int = None, end: int = None):
    if not start:
        start = 0
    if not end:
        end = len(sentence)

    spacedword = " ".join(word)
    indices = []
    cur = sentence.find(word, start)

    # Find all occurrences of the word
    while cur >= 0 and cur < end + len(word) - 1:
        # Add to list
        indices.append(cur) 

        # Next occurrence
        cur = cur + len(word)
        cur = sentence.find(word, cur, end + len(word) - 1)
    print("\t" + str(indices)) # To check indices

    # Replace word with spaced-out word
    while len(indices) > 0:
        index = indices.pop()
        sa = sentence[:index]
        sb = sentence[index:index + len(word)]
        sc = sentence[index + len(word):]
        sb = sb.replace(word, spacedword)
        sentence = sa + sb + sc

    return sentence
```

How can I widespace a given word (exact match, ignoring punctuation) within a certain range in Python? An efficient solution that meets all the expectations is preferred, though I am pretty flexible with the results.

Comment: Should your second example have an endrange of 5 rather than 4?

Comment: Thanks my bad. I am just editing the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the simplest, and probably most efficient, way to "widespace" an entire string is:

```
' '.join(s)
```

This is because strings are iterables that iterate each individual character, so if you pass one to `join`, it joins up all of the characters with the separate in between each pair.

So, how to you widespace part of the string? Easy: slice it, `join` just the part you want to widespace, then merge it back together:

```
s[:start] + ' '.join(s[start:end]) + s[end:]
```

This isn't quite the same interface you asked for, but then I'm not sure what `word` is supposed to do in your question, so I just wrote the simplest thing, that widespaces *everything*, and hopefully you can figure out how to map it to what you want:

```
>>> s = 'foo foo foo foo foo foo foo'
>>> s[:8] + ' '.join(s[8:15]) + s[15:]
'foo foo f o o   f o o foo foo foo'
```

Note that this also allows you to use `start=None, end=None` default values, and they'll automatically work with the same meanings as in slicing, `range`, etc.: `None` means start at the start or end at the end.

This will be very efficient, but probably not as efficient as creating a custom C extension that reserves the space for `len(s) + end - start` at the start and then loops over the characters in C.

Comment: Can you please give me some examples of how your algorithm works and how it meets the expectations?

Comment: @Oighea Edited. But, as I said, I don't understand how your expectations work. For example, what happens if half of a `foo` is within the range? Do you widespace the whole thing, just the half within the range, or neither? Whatever the answer is, you should be able to work it out pretty easily: first split the string into the pre-, middle-, and post- parts, then do your replacing only on the middle, then just add them back together.

Comment: You widespace the whole thing. Edited for further clarity.

Comment: I have added an additional note regarding the definition of a `word`. Here, a `word` is just a substring to be matched. Additionally, an "exact match" of a word is one that is not surrounded by word characters. When matching `"OMG"`, `"OMG,"` counts, but not `"zOMG"` nor `"OMG!"`.